# Unable to read file from other user account programmatically (C++) in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, file, winapi, visual-c++

I have created a text file with some logs in the one User account in Windows using the following functions:

```
WORD wBOM = 0xFEFF;

    HANDLE hFile = ::CreateFileW(filePath, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,CREATE_NEW,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

            ::WriteFile(hFile, &wBOM, sizeof(WORD), &NumberOfBytesWritten, NULL);
            ::CloseHandle(hFile);
```

Now, when I read this file from other user account programmatically, I am unable to open file and read its content.

I am using the below function to read from other user account.

```
CFile file;
        CFileException *exp = NULL;
        if(!file.Open( logAppExecPath,CFile::modeReadWrite | CFile::shareDenyNone,exp))
        {

        if(exp != NULL)
        {
            TCHAR ErrorMsg[MAX_PATH];
            exp->GetErrorMessage(ErrorMsg,MAX_PATH);
            AfxMessageBox(L"XML Creation while AppExecLogs : "+ CString(ErrorMsg));
            exp->Delete();

        }
        }
```

However, whenever I read from the same user account the above functions work perfectly and opens and read the file properly.

Both user accounts are administrator accounts.

In conclusion, writing a file programmatically in one user account and reading from other user account gives exception that the "File Does not Exist" .. but the fact is that File exists and I can open that file manually using clicking.

Comment: Are you sure you have the rights for it? Because it sounds as if you don't.

Comment: Hello @RedX  ... Thanks for the reply ...Infact I did one more test that I created the file in Limited Account and tried to read it in Administrator account ... but this time also it failed... But in Limited Account I am able to open file using CFile()

Comment: @JoãoAugusto : File path is:  C:\ProgramData\Limited_User\logs.txt

Answer (score 2):

By default user's profiles are accessable only to that user. Furthermore, Windows no standard way to access any other user's profile.

Your best option is to use a common/shared location, either in `C:\ProgramData\` (with the permissions set as needed) or in the common documents folders. Where depends on what the file is.